# How to stop fast clicking animation happening jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an image slide show. There will be a set of images on the left and user can click the up or down image to see the rest of the image. I am showing only 3 Images at a time.
The way I did it is I slide up the first one, move it to the bottom. At the same time, sliding the 4th one up to show it.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#goup").click(function(e) {

    $("#imgslide > img:first")
        .slideUp(500,function(e){
            $(this).appendTo("#imgslide");
            });

    $("#imgslide > img:eq(3)").slideToggle({direction:"up"},500);
    // move the paragraph with the image    index sync  
    $("#product_description > div:first")
        .appendTo("#product_description");  
});
```

I don't have any id or class on those images ( Gonna use ajax to produce these `<img>` tag )
It worked when I click slowly. If I double click fast, the 3rd image is gone.
Is there any way I can stop user from fast clicking or can it wait for the last action finish to go to the next one?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#goup").click(function(e) {

   $("#imgslide > img:first")
       .slideUp(500,function(e){
           $(this).appendTo("#imgslide");
           });

   $("#imgslide > img:eq(3)").slideToggle({direction:"up"},500);
   // move the paragraph with the image    index sync  
   $("#product_description > div:first")
       .appendTo("#product_description");
   return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, You can disable the double click  event on the element ,So the element will not respond to the double click event.

```
$("#goup").dblclick(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer further so that future visitors to the site will understand how your solution solves the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Put a variable boolean in your click function to check whether imgslide in  transition/animation mode. if clicked is true return "donothing" once slidetoggle completed set the it to false.

```
var clicked = false;
$("#goup").click(function(e) {

if(clicked) return;

clicked= true;

$("#imgslide > img:first")
   .slideUp(500,function(e){
       $(this).appendTo("#imgslide");
       });

$("#imgslide > img:eq(3)").slideToggle({direction:"up",complete:function(){
  clicked= false;

}},500);
// move the paragraph with the image    index sync  
$("#product_description > div:first")
   .appendTo("#product_description");
return false;
});
```